# Скрытие меню при скроле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть появление меню при клике

```
$('.menu-btn').click(function(){
    $('#mb-menu').slideToggle(500);
});`
```

Как сделать обратное исчезновение этого меню при скроллинге мышкой, например `slideUp(500)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так?

```js
$('.menu-btn').click(function(){
  $('#mb-menu').slideToggle(500);
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
  $('#mb-menu').slideUp(500);
});
```

```css
#mb-menu{
  background-color:wheat;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='menu-btn'>///</button>
<div id='mb-menu'>123</div>
<br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr><br><hr>
```

Comment: Отлично. А как теперь сделать, чтобы код работал, если сама кнопка появляется после скроллинга скажем на 200px вниз (просто кнопка '.menu-btn' сама появляется после скроллинга)

Comment: @ПавелА.А. я не очень понял, можете показать пример?

Comment: @ПавелА.А. можно или тут https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/pYrQPj или в новом вопросе на stackoverflow увидеть побольше кода html и css чтобы не выдумывать